# Loading images on tableView in Background getting this issue

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

> Stack: (0xb1771f 0xb4f602 0x58e62 0x90ec4a24 0x90eb6cf2 0x90eb6781 0x90eb65c6)
>   2012-01-31 19:58:10.920 FINS[7353:560f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x708e000 of class NSConcreteData autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking

//code for image on tableView in background

```
dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
//this will start the image loading in bg
dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{              
    NSData *image = [[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:NewsImagestring]] autorelease];
    //this will set the image when loading is finished
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{                                
        imgView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:image];              
        [image release];
        [imgView release];              
    });                     
});
```

Comment: Why are you releasing imgView? It makes no sense to me.

Comment: If you're down-marking, can you please comment reason why you are doing so. I'm guessing in this case because "it doesn't read as a question" otherwise how can we expect posters to 'learn'?

Answer (score 0):

You are releasing image which is in autorelease pool. So this is crashing your app. comment this line check again.